# Convert Geoid File Types

Tags: datum, geoid, vertical-transformation

Anyone know what I can use to convert a geoid surface stored as , BYN into .GTX for use with PROJ4?

The CCG2013A vertical datum and geoid model from NRCan is only available, as far as I can find, in BYN format.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a demo verion of the Hydromagic software from https://www.eye4software.com/download/

It includes a geoid converter freeware: https://www.eye4software.com/hydromagic/documentation/manual/utilities/geoid-file-conversion/

Supported file types are `.geo, .ggf, .gsf, .byn, .bin, .grd, .txt, .gtx` as source and destination.

They offer a bunch of geoid files in their .geo format at https://www.eye4software.com/hydromagic/documentation/geoid-models/

Disclosure: I'm not affiliated with the software company.

Answer (score 1):

[GDAL will support BYN](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_byn.html) files in an upcoming release.  However, it is unclear when this release will be compiled for windows.

In the meantime, I've [uploaded converted GTX files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11fydtqjv8w1xk-cZusen7z39DJwBa1M2) for HT2_0 and CGG2013 so that they are easily accessible until the GDAL capabilities come into effect.