How to convert a BYN type file into either a EGM or GRD file to upload into my data collector
I'm trying to upload a geoid model onto my Leica CS14 data collector but the data collector only accepts EGM file and Grd/Gsf files but when downloading the geoid model from the Canadian government page it only downloads as a BYN file and I can't seem to find any solutions on Google. Any advice?

Are you using Leica's Captivate or Infinity software? I can find a document on using Infinity to convert the .byn files. Link may be weird. I used this search: convert canadian .byn file to us .bin file

Related but old question/answers (from 2017): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259639/convert-geoid-file-types
